# Python : Convert time format to unix_timeformat

Tags: python, time-format

I have a time format like this

```
t = "2012-03-20T08:31:00-05:00"
```

I can extract the time contents using RegEx like this.

```
p = re.compile("(\d{4})\-(\d\d)\-(\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)[\-|+]\d\d:\d\d")
matches = p.findall(t)
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to convert this format directly to unix_timestamp without using RegEx ? Is there a calendar library or something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime):

```
time.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%Z")
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work with numeric time zone offsets.  [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) should be able to handle your format:

```
dateutil.parser.parse(t)
```

Alternatively, you could split your string before the numeric offset:

```
t, offset_sign, offset = t[:-6], t[-6], t[-5:]
t = time.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
offset = time.strptime(offset, "%H:%M")
```

Comment: ValueError: time data '2012-03-20T08:31:00-05:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%Z'

Comment: @anjanesh yes, it seems it can't handle numeric time zones.  See my update.

Answer (score 2):

`datetime.datetime.strptime` is your friend :)

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Answer (score 1):

Use [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) from the time module